# algorithmic idea using greedy strategy

Tags: algorithm, greedy

So I just finished taking a test and thought that I would ask you guys about a question that stumped me. I was asked to come up with the algorithmic idea using `greedy strategy` on an ascending array of n numbers, where `A[i] + A[j] = T`. T is just a number that is given to see if the two numbers add up to it. We are to keep it to `O(n)`. I'm wasn't sure on how to do this properly.

The way that I suggested was to take `A[i] + A[j] > T` if it wasn't then `A[i + 1] + A[j + 1]` until you found an answer that was greater than T. Once you found that it was greater than T you would go from A[0] to A[j-1] and see if it matches any of the cases. I don't think my idea is O(n) though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you need to find all of the pairs (i,j) such that A[i] + A[j] = T, or just any particular pair?

Comment: Just any pair not all pairs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that for each big value of A[i] starting at the end of the list, you will search for the smaller value of j such that A[i]+A[j]=T, if such a j exists.  If the array were unordered, this would be an O(n^2) loop nest.

The greedy part is that you never need to "go backward" with the value of j because the values of A are ascending.  I.e. when you decrease the value of i, all the possible correct values of j must be bigger than the current value.

In code:

```
i = n - 1;
j = 0;
while (j <= i)
  if (A[i] + A[j] < T)
    j++;
  else if (A[i] + A[j] > T)
    i--;
  else {
    printf("A[%d] + A[%d] = %d\n", i, j, T);
    break;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as exactly a greedy strategy, but the standard solution to this problem is to maintain a left index L and a right index R. Initially these are set to 1 and n. If A[L] + A[R] < T then increment L by 1. If A[L] + A[R] > T then decrease R by 1. Once you reach L = R, if you haven't found a solution then no solution exists.

Comment: That's what I thought. I wasn't 100% sure if I was approaching it the right way